# Ajax show custom post data form & script

Tags: ajax, javascript, forms

I have a wp site with persons details saved as ***custom post type*** officials.

I want to create a form to get input and show the corresponding results of the person using ajax request.

Like inputting roll no. and date of birth and click submit to get result details on the same page with using ? query string in other php file.

Please help me.
Thankyou.

**Edit:**

In Simply:

I want to know know to get input like roll no and date of birth and show their result using ajax without loading the page on click submit button.

I don't know to how to prepare html and java script.

Please help me.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Don't you know how to interrupt a form sending with javascript? Or how to use the wp-ajax.php? Because now is is very hard to help you. [SO - how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edited.  I want to know how to use ajax.